# Use a Table as a Variable in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables classroom and computer and currently computer is a variable in the table classroom

```
CREATE TABLE classroom_tbl
(
   room_id        INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   teacher_name   VARCHAR(30),
   subject_name   VARCHAR(30),
   computer       VARCHAR(30)
);
```

and I want to make it so instead of being a VARCHAR in the classroom table the variable computer calls the computer table

```
CREATE TABLE computer_tbl
(
   computer_id       INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   computer_type     VARCHAR(30),
   computer_status   INT
);
```

Is there any way to do this? I've tried UNION and INNER JOIN but I always get an error that says that my columns are different sizes. Which makes sense because classroom is bigger than computer. Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: If the `computer` column in your `classroom_tbl` is a foreign key into the `computer_tbl` you need to define it as an `INT` and use it to store the `computer_id`

Comment: Can you post an example of a couple `classroom_tbl` and `computer_tbl` rows, with an explanation of how the contents of the `classroom_tbl.computer` column relates to the `computer_tbl` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are new to SQL and have some experience in programming. SQL does not have variables like we do have in programming langauages such as C/C++/java. Rather SQL tables relate to each other with relationships such as foreign key relationship. You need to go through SQL tutorials for understanding more about relationships, here is a link to one of those:

http://www.functionx.com/sql/Lesson11.htm

In order to use the JOINS you need to have Primary-foreign key relationship between the two tables. You may have to create your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE classroom_tbl
(
   room_id        INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   teacher_name   VARCHAR(30),
   subject_name   VARCHAR(30),
   computer_id    INT REFERENCES computer_tbl(computer_id)
);
```

Comment: I don't want computer_id to just reference the computer_id in the computer table, I want computer_id to reference the entire table. Is that possible?

Comment: @AnnabelleGreen: no, you cannot "reference a table" in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Since a given classroom can have many computers in it, but a given computer can only be in one classroom at a time, it makes more sense to have classroom as a foreign key on the computer table, rather than vice versa:

```
CREATE TABLE classroom_tbl
(
   room_id        INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   teacher_name   VARCHAR(30),
   subject_name   VARCHAR(30)
); 

CREATE TABLE computer_tbl
(
   computer_id       INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   computer_type     VARCHAR(30),
   computer_status   INT,
   room_id           INT
);
```

To see which computers are in each room, try a query like:

```
select r.room_id, r.teacher_name, r.subject_name,
       c.computer_id, c.computer_type, c.computer_status
from classroom_tbl r
left join computer_tbl c on r.room_id = c.room_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this, what I wanted to do was not possible. You can only reference other columns in other tables or create foriegn keys. Unfortunatly you cannot reference an entire table.